# if(element:contains) constantly returns true no matter what value or elements are involved

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, contains

I'm attempting to hide a form's submit button until a certain kind of file has been selected using jQuery.

```
<input type="file" id="file">
<input type="submit" id="submit">

if($("#file:contains('.png')")) {
    alert("Yep, that's a PNG image");

    $('#submit').show();
}
```

jQuery constantly returns true no matter what value or elements are involved, as soon as the page loads the alert comes up and informs me that the file input contains ".png"

I understand this isn't really the right way to do this, by the way. I believe you can get around this by just using inspect element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling jQuery with a selector will always return a jQuery object which is always truthy that is why the `if` condition is return `true` always.

Also `:contains` checks for text content of the element, not value so you need to check whether the value of the file is having .png

```js
$('#file').change(function() {
  var png = /\.png$/.test($('#file').val());
  if (png) {
    alert("Yep, that's a PNG image");
  }
  $('#submit').toggle(png);
})
```

```css
#submit {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file">
<input type="submit" id="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ava8q1pb/1/)**

I hope you will be doing this in a `change event` of `input file`. So I suggest below work around to achieve this:

```
$('#file').change(function(e){
      var file = $(this).val();
      if(file!="" && file != null)
      {
          var ext = file.split('.').pop();//get the type
          if(ext=="png")
          {
               alert("Yep, that's a PNG image");
               $('#submit').show();
          }
          else
          {
               alert("Yawk!! Bad file");
               $('#submit').hide();
          }
      }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the sensible path to take. My question was just regarding why it always returned true. Can you unhide the submit button with inspect element?

Comment: Your selector is improper buddy.. That's not what `:contains` intend to do.. **[Check here](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**